# Numeric comparision not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (parseInt(job_level_filter_val.length) == 0 && parseInt(education_filter_val.lenght) == 0 && parseInt(filter_type_val.length) == 0) {
    console.log('blank');
    //$('li[data-listing="jobs"]').fadeIn();
} else {
    console.log('not blank');
}
```

This is my code but its not working. When every variabe length is 0 it returns "not blank" in console.
When i compare every field seperately it returns expected result but does not work when all cases were combined with "AND".

Comment: Why you used `parseInt()` while your value is int?

Comment: typo error education_filter_val.lenght ? it should be length

Comment: not working on both case. If i put parseInt or not

Comment: `length` property always return `Number`. `parseInt` is not needed...

Comment: you have a typo in parseInt(education_filter_val.lenght)

Comment: what is the type of job_level_filter_val ?

Comment: printing job_level_filter_val (this kind of value) in console returns number never NaN

Comment: they represents array. @roy

Comment: Have you checked after correcting parseInt(education_filter_val.lenght) to parseInt(education_filter_val.lengh)?

Comment: i did it with parseInte on every field and with out parseInt but when all field returns 0 its showing not blank on console

Comment: solved it  thanks @alpha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo error "`parseInt(education_filter_val.lenght)`" Use **length** instead of **lenght**

And Length in javascript is return number only you want check zero or not like the below code

```
if (!job_level_filter_val.length && !education_filter_val.length &&  !filter_type_val.length) {
    console.log('blank');
    //$('li[data-listing="jobs"]').fadeIn();
} else {
    console.log('not blank');
}
```